# DDoS resistant network application design

Tags: java, security, network-programming

Okay, for my application I'm trying to decide on an architecture that's as DDoS resistant as possible. Obviously it will never be perfect but I'd like protection against simple attacks.

There's a few that I've thought of so far:

1) Single thread per connection.

This method seems to have unbelievable scalability problems, and with a tonne of connections, having too many threads seems like it would be a scheduling nightmare for the OS.

2) 2 threads. first thread will accept connections and append them to a list, the second thread loops through the list (with the proper synchro here) and checks if there's anything in the `InputStream`. Upon finding something, read a line. Any of the actual work will be done, including the reply, in a new event thread. The new thread is just passed the line that is read.

This method seems to have even bigger problems. It appears as though a simple `cat /dev/urandom | telnet server port` would lock it down.

3) This is similar to #2, but only read a single byte from each connection at each iteration, and processing it as a string when I get to a newline byte.

This seems like my best option so far, but it means that if the attack initiates a lot of connections and sends input on all of them, it could slow the loop down considerably.

Are there any other potential architectures that might be better suited for the job?

Comment: The problem with your solutions is that they seem to be trying to rate limit, which is the opposite of what you want to do.

When faced with a DDoS attack, you want to INCREASE your capacity so you can absorb the DDoS traffic in addition to your normal user traffic. Rate limiting will drop both user and attacker connections, but the attacker doesn't care so it only hurts the user.

Comment: @akirilov what do you mean they rate limit? The first one is the naive approach that everyone learns at the beginning. The others are just architectures that I've come up with, that I've noticed flaws in. DDoS has been a big thing lately, so I'm afflicted with seeing the potential problems before I write it. I don't know what to do. Should I just accept that DDoS is a force to be reckoned with? The only one that I've designed with the intention of preventing DDoS is the third one, but the other 2 are obviously worse

Comment: Basically, these approaches only have two worker threads at most. This is not nearly enough for a large amount of legitimate traffic, let alone for a DDoS attack. Basically, DDoS relies on flooding you with lots of garbage connections which starves the legitimate users (they're stuck waiting for the server to handle the garbage connections and often end up timing out).

Comment: @akirilov I should probably have mentioned that the worker threads are just for finding input. Any actions to be taken would spawn event threads.

Comment: ah ok. In that case, the idea in #2 is on the right track and would help mitigate a very simple DDoS attack that sends empty requests, but I think that's an unlikely scenario. Basically, I would go with the one that could process the most connections the fastest (probably #2, although I would also advocate for having multiple threads that can accept connections). DDoS is essentially a very inelegant yet difficult attack to mitigate. It's a battle of brute-forcing. Your best bet is to have a lot of powerful servers.

Comment: @akirilov well #2 isn't even a power struggle, it actually will just read input forever until it finds a `\n` from a single connection. Full DoS with 1kb/s lol. That's what gave me the idea of the third option. It seems to treat all connections fairly

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not explaining this well. DDoS assumes the attacker has a HUGE number of connections. Treating everyone fairly doesn't matter if 50% of your traffic is garbage. Moreover, if you only process one byte at a time, even during normal operations your service will be very slow (especially if requests are large and need to be fully assembled before they can be processed) I wouldn't really take DDoS into account when creating the server. Just optimize it for processing many requests quickly and then just scale that up. Responsiveness is your best defense.

Comment: @akirilov do you have any suggestions for optimizing the processing of many requests? Which may be synonymous with this question? I've never really dealt with scalability before.

Comment: Someone else could probably help more here but from what I've seen the best way is to have a pool of worker threads and assign a thread to each new connection. That thread will handle the request from start to finish. All you need to do then is increase the number of threads to handle more connection simultaneously However, if you have too many threads you basically get into the same problem as #3 where they are all getting in each other's way and nothing gets done. There is a balance and the only way to find it that I know of is to run some stress tests.

Answer (score 0):

Large companies have entire teams that spend all day every day working to combat various DOS attacks.  It' too much to discuss here.  After trivial mitigation techniques (like SYN-cookies, etc.), your best bet is simply to have sufficient capacity to "eat it".

I would recommend writing your code for *efficiency* and then running it on a hosted service like Google's or Amazon's and let them deal with fending of DOS attacks and scaling your service to handle such spikes.